# Guardar la selección de un CheckBox en Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, checkbox

¿Cómo guardar la selección de un `CheckBox`? Únicamente los *checks* seleccionados, guardar y cuando quiera consultarlos de nuevo, pueda ver los *checks* marcados:

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub CargaDatosDefault()

    Conexion.Conectar()

    Dim sSQLQuery As String = vbNullString
    chkGiros.Items.Clear()

    sSQLQuery = "SELECT    girIndice, RIGHT ('000' + CONVERT (VARCHAR (3), girIndice), 3) + ' - ' + girDescripcion AS 'GIRO'" & vbCr
    sSQLQuery &= "FROM    " & LibreriasGenerales2015.cls_CC_Giro.TablaNombre & vbCr
    sSQLQuery &= " ORDER BY girDescripcion " & vbCr

    Dim adoConsultaBasica As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Nothing
    If Conexion.Consultar(sSQLQuery, adoConsultaBasica) Then
        Do While adoConsultaBasica.Read
            chkGiros.Items.Add(adoConsultaBasica.Item("GIRO"))
        Loop
        adoConsultaBasica.Close()
    End If

    Dim iContador As Integer
    if iContador = 0 To chkGiros.Items.Count - 1
        chkGiros.CheckedItems(iContador, True)
    Next

        sSQLQuery = "SELECT    MarcaCompIndice, RIGHT ('000' + CONVERT (VARCHAR (3), MarcaCompIndice), 3) + ' - ' + MarcaCompNombre AS 'COMPETENCIA'" & vbCr
        sSQLQuery &= "FROM    MARCAS_DE_LA_COMPETENCIA"
        sSQLQuery &= " ORDER BY MarcaCompNombre " & vbCr

        If Conexion.Consultar(sSQLQuery, adoConsultaBasica) Then
            Do While adoConsultaBasica.Read
                chkMaquinariaCompetencia.Items.Add(adoConsultaBasica.Item("COMPETENCIA"))
            Loop
            adoConsultaBasica.Close()
        End If

        Conexion.Desconectar()


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Para guardar el estado de los checkboxes puedes usar My.Settings en Visual Studio, aunque según cómo trabajes o la cantidad de checkboxes que necesites, puedes usar otras alternativas.

**Para My.Settings en Visual Studio:**
Puedes hacer una prueba siguiendo este ejemplo como idea muy básica:

```
Menú superior: Proyecto/Propiedades de [nombre de tu solución]
```

En la nueva ventana, en la izquierda selecciona “Configuración”
Añade una nueva variable

**Nombre:** myCheckBox1

**Tipo:** Boolean

**Ámbito:** Usuario

**Valor:** False

Para experimentar la idea, cuando cierres la aplicación o el formulario en cuestión añade este código:

```
Private Sub Form_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
If CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked then 
My.Settings. myCheckBox1 = true 
Else
My.Settings. myCheckBox1 = false
End if
End Sub
```

Cuando se abra el formulario por primera vez, aplica el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub Form_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
If My.Settings. myCheckBox1 = true then
CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
Else
CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
End if
End sub
```

Según la cantidad de checkboxes que tengas puedes usar un array que almacene de buen principio el estado de tus My.Settings y así aplicarlo más adelante mediante un For.

```
Dim myArray(3) as Boolean
myArray(0) = My.Settings. myCheckBox1
myArray(1) = My.Settings. myCheckBox2
myArray(2) = My.Settings. myCheckBox3
```

Notas:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019